# Django ORM Query multple keywords and retrun multiple list of of objects with single query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

These are my model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=50
    )


class Question(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100
    )
    topic = models.ForeignKey(
        Topic,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

For example, I have many questions with the `topic` from many topics, I am trying to query `english`, `biology` topic-related question.

and this my current query:

```
question = Question.objects.filter(
        topic__name__in=["english", "biology"]
    ).values('title', 'id', 'topic')
```

It returns all the `biology` and `english` related question.

I dont want exactly like this.

I want, it will return all the question that `english` and `biology` related questions but should be with group, like, all the English related objects should be in a separate lists and all the biology-related objects should be another separate list.

there can be many topics, and all the query should be retrun in a list and in that list, there should be multiple list of objects based on the topic.

the output look like this:

```
[
    {
        'english': [here will be all the biology related objecs in list],
        'biology': [here will be all the biology related objects in list]
    }
]
```

I hope you got problem.

Can anyone help me in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice to go the other way around: we first filter on the topic, and then retrieve the related `Question`s with a `.prefetch_related(..)` call:

```
qs = Topic.objects.filter(
    name__in=['english', 'biology']
).prefetch_related('question')
```

Then we can construct a dictionary with:

```
result = {
    t.name: [{'id': q.id, 'title': q.title} for q in t.question_set.all()]
    for t in qs
}
```

Comment: Thanks, You made my day